# PHP - Simulate constructor without object instantiation

Tags: php

I would like to create a class with **many public static methods**.
These methods are going to use one property that has to be dynamically defined before the usage.

Consider the following class. I want to call `Foo::bar()`. But I want to somehow define `$prop` right before this.

```
class Foo{
 private static $prop;

 public static function bar(){
  echo self::$prop + 1;
 }
}
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you exactly know **why** you want to use "many static methods"?

Comment: What value do you want?

Comment: @B001ᛦ the question is whether there is a hook "on before method called".

Comment: The question @B001ᛦ asks is still very relevant. The answer will tell us if this is a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) or just poor design. If you tell us why, we might be able to understand the underlying issue you're having and might be able to suggest a better solution. In general, static methods should be avoided in many situations (not saying they don't have a purpose, but they tend to introduce hard dependencies, which you want to avoid.

Comment: _... the question is whether there..._ Does that mean you don't answer the question in my comment above? :)

Comment: @B001ᛦ I want to create an array of dynamic request headers. Every static method is an HTTP request to external services. Each one has to use the headers array. Class here is only a namespace because instantiating it does not make sense.

Comment: Why not just create a protected property or static method that returns an array with the headers? Then you just call it from the methods you need them in? And looking at your example, there you could just give the property a default value.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson because copy-pasting code is a poor design! I want it to exist in one place only.

Comment: I never said copy/paste. I said that you create _one_ property or method that returns the array. An example: `protected static $headers = ['header1', 'header2'];` and then just use `$headers = self::$headers;` in your other methods. Alt. `protected static function getHeaders() { return ['header1', 'header2']; }` and use it: `$headers = self::headers()`. That's no "copy/paste".

Comment: Hi @spoorwe! I understand that you are new here and that Magnus,and BOO1 might seem cold. Try to take deep breaths, they are not attacking you or your code... they are just asking for clarification :D They need to know the common topic before answering the question.